# TinyMCE formatting at the insertion point

Tags: tinymce-4

When I place the insertion point at the end of a formatted word the formatting carries on. Is it possible to have TinyMCE use the formatting from after that word?

For example, when I have "**word1** word2" and I place the insertion point directly after "word1" I'd like to get "**word1** word3 word2" but I actually get "**word1 word3** word2". The formatting is picked up from left of the cursor, whereas I'd like it to pick it up from the right ... hope that makes sense. :-)

Is there a configuration option I can set for this?